# Testing a JS web app with jUnit - Issues with the .click() command not resolving as planned

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, webdriver

(Java, JUnit, Selenium, WebDriver)

For my job I've been tasked with testing a web application that primarily runs as an SWF file, but for the purposes of test automation, we have a JavaScript version.

I am trying to do a simple task. I want to click the logout button. Here is the snippet of code dealing with that.

```
// Clicks the log out button
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement logout = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='flow']/div[1]/div/div[7]/div/div[3]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[4]/div/img"));
actions.moveToElement(logout).click().build().perform();
```

So, running this script has odd functionality. The button will not be clicked, but upon manually hovering my mouse over the button, the button will (without any other manual input) act as though it was clicked and never released.

So the two problems are moveToElement(logout) does not move me to the button, and the .click().build().perform() does not function how I expected it to either.

Been researching and trying different answers all week. I'm hoping I'm just making a stupid mistake. Does anyone have a suggestion?

EDIT: So far we have tried to find a new xpath (current xpath seems to be the xpath to the image of the button), record the click on the Selenium IDE (Selenium IDE doesn't recognize the button), and attempt a direct .click() command.

Comment: holy brittle xpath batman................

Comment: Is the element really a button? It looks like you are performing the click on the image, may that be the problem? Is there maybe some JS which is triggered by the click?

Comment: Probably the image. How would I go about finding the xpath of the actual button? I used firepath to get this current xpath.

Comment: Does direct clicking on the element not work? `driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='flow']/div[1]/div/div[7]/div/div[3]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[4]/div/img")).click()` like this? if its failing what error you get with this?

Comment: Just tried direct clicking. Sadly, no avail. This could very well be a problem with the xpath itself as DaDaDom said. Using firebug/firepath I am attempting to find any sort of id value or xpath to the button itself.

I would imagine clicking on the image would work, since it represents the button, right? Edit: Can't seem to find any id or different xpath. Also tried to record clicking it through the IDE so I could export it, but the IDE doesn't seem to recognize it's there. Using WebDriver and Eclipse, by the way, just to clarify.